# ApiNotActivatedMapError for simple html page using google-places-api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to create a simple html page (I'd later like to add an autocomplete input there) that include google-places-api.
I have an api-key (which is enabled) but I still get an error message.

Here is my html-

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

but I get this error message-
[image]

and in the console I get - **Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError**

I can't understand what the problem is.. Appreciate anybody's help

Comment: **2018**: Click enable [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/maps-backend.googleapis.com?filter=category:maps&id=fd73ab50-9916-4cde-a0f6-dc8be0a0d425).

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько TIL Google JavaScript Map API !== Google Maps Embed API

Comment: @Илья Зеленько thank you. it worked.

Answer (score 356):

To enable Api do this

1. Go to `API Manager`
2. Click on `Overview`
3. Search for `Google Maps JavaScript API`(Under `Google Maps APIs`). Click on that
4. You will find `Enable` button there. Click to enable API.

OR
 **You can try this url**: 
[Maps JavaScript API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-backend.googleapis.com?q=Google%20Maps%20JavaScript%20API&id=fd73ab50-9916-4cde-a0f6-dc8be0a0d425&project=windy-furnace-180806)

Hope this will solve the problem of enabling API.

Comment: as mentioned by the op and as is my case i have both javascript api and distance matrix apis enabled already and still getting that error

Comment: Where is the API Manager? I don't find those options? Could you send a URL?

Comment: Check this: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=windy-furnace-180806&q=Google%20Maps%20JavaScript%20API

Comment: For this to work, I had to enable the APIs, and *then* create the key. Make sure you don't do it the other way around.

Comment: For me it is saying you don't have permission to enable it. What I have to do now?

Comment: For places API you should also enable Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: Those who can not find, type "Maps JavaScript API" in search box

Comment: But I dont need Google Maps javascript API, just need Places API! Not using any maps, just autocomplete field. If Places API required another to be enabled, shouldnt that come with it automatically?

Comment: 2020: It says I dont have permission to "enable". Now what to do?

Comment: This API project is not authorized to use this API. Places API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Comment: Works Fine. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for the direct link. For some reason I get a blank page if I try to access the API by navigating through interface.
I did change the project name at the end of the URL though.

Answer (score 106):

Assuming you already have a application created under google developer console, 
Follow the below steps

1. Go to the following link `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?` you will be getting the below page [image]
2. Click on **ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES** you will be directed to following page [image]
3. Select the desired option - in this case "Maps JavaScript API"
4. Click ENABLE button as below,
   [image]

Note: Please use a server to load the `html` file

Comment: It says "You dont have permission to to this". How to "enable" it?

Comment: This API project is not authorized to use this API. Places API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Comment: I'm facing the same permission issue, what next, I know I cannot trick Google by enabling through inspect element like I would most insecure sites. what else can I do?

Comment: @PreciousTom I didn't get you

Comment: @PreciousTom I was having same issue and that was because I was outside of the project. You have to select the project from the dropdown and then you'll be able to enable the key

Comment: Thanks ❤ @Aravind

Comment: I am getting billing error `You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project` . How can I use it for free ?

Comment: @NoobCoder - I used this one for free

Comment: @Aravind Did you provide your card details ? If yes, then it is still free or some amount deducted ?

Comment: @NoobCoder no I didn't give my card information. may be it's a new release that they had it expects card details

Answer (score 29):

as of Jan 2017, unfortunately @Adi's answer, while it seems like it should work, does not.   (Google's API key process is buggy)

you'll need to click "get a key" from this link:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

also I strongly recommend you don't ever choose "secure key" until you are ready to switch to production.   I did http referrer restrictions on a key and afterwards was unable to get it working with localhost, even after disabling security for the key.  I had to create a new key for it to work again.

Comment: the get key from this 1 link finally created a working key for me. ty. all the other links i clicked to get key would get me the same non working one :S

Comment: @bia.migueis I affirm (Apr 2018). Tried getting a new key several times and all gave ApiNotActivatedMapError. This link worked (although I thought I'd been there before, so maybe one has to just keep trying, not sure)

Comment: Just giving me thumbs up on this method.  I screwed around in the API console for about an hour before trying this and it worked in a matter of seconds.  Google needs to get their s**t together.

Comment: @JasonS This bug is still around as on 2022. I had to go to key & make some dummy changes & update it again to make it work with newly added API.

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried following the advice on the linked help page?  The help page at http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors says:

> **ApiNotActivatedMapError**
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API is not activated on your API project. You may need to enable the Google Maps JavaScript API under APIs in the Google Developers Console.
>
> See [Obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

So check that the key you are using has **Google Maps JavaScript API** enabled.

Comment: But I dont need Google Maps Javascript API, just need Places API! Not using any maps, just autocomplete field. If Places API required another to be enabled, shouldnt that come with it automatically?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. To fix the error:

1. Open the console menu `Gallery Menu` and select `API Manager`.
2. On the left, click `Credentials` and then click `New Credentials`.
3. Click `Create Credentials`.
4. Click `API KEY`.
5. Click `Navigator Key` (there are more options; It depends on when consumed).

You must use this new `API Navigator Key`, generated by the system.

Comment: Is 'consumed' a typo? If so, what did you mean to write?

Comment: @TigerSpirt I am facing same problem. i have tried to generate new API Key but do not find "Navigator Key". Friends please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 I had to go and enable the javascript maps api as well as enabling the  places api. I only need this for the autocomplete feature for a billing form I created. message me if your confused

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk to use the places library,click on Create Credentials tab on Google Cloud Console, and create the api key for
the Maps JavaScript API.
Sample Code below:

```
    <input type="text" id="txtFullAddress" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<Your-API-Key>&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var inputAddressField = document.getElementById("txtFullAddress");
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputAddressField);
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                alert(mesg);
            });
        });
    </script>
```