# Angular.js googleMap API json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: angularjs, json, google-maps, callback, jsonp

I red all previous posts:
* i added :    **&callback=JSON_CALLBACK**
* i also tried simple $http.get but it leads to: '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**'
* i also tried to define jsonpCallbackParam to'**json_callback**' from just **callback** and added **format: 'jsonp'**
*also tried to read documentation about $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url) (well i didn't understand much :-( 
On F12 -> source, i see that the required data is returned but on the console log i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

please advise

```
var autoJsonpUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?region=il&origins=tel-aviv&destinations=jerusalem&key=AIzaSyD3xhn92KwStkZAg-rZueAFI1LooRLpND0' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

var options =
{
     jsonpCallbackParam: 'json_callback',
     cache: false
};

$http.jsonp(autoJsonpUrl, options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoint `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/` does not support `JSONP`, instead you could consider to utilize [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) as demonstrated below:

```js
angular.module('mapApp', [])

    .controller("mapCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.routeInfo = null;
        var distanceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        var distanceRequest = { region: "il", origins: ["tel-aviv"], destinations: ["jerusalem"], travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC};
        distanceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix(distanceRequest, function (response, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                console.log('An error occured: ' + status);
            }
            else {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                   $scope.routeInfo = response;    
                });
                
            }
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <pre>{{routeInfo | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur reply but in order to check it i need to know where should i insert my API-KEY, can u please direct me where in the code shell i do so?

Comment: @LifeLess, here we go `<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=--YOUR  KEY GOES HERE--"></script>`

Comment: Ok, do u know now how i activate the map error referring to the current error: API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Comment: @LifeLess, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38056246/1375553) should do the trick