# Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError altough Google Maps JavaScript API is enabled

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-api-javascript-client, agm

I want to display a simple Google Maps on my Website. I followed several tutorials and they always tell me the same: Generate API KEY, Enable the Google Maps API and type in this code...
First it loads correctly with the latitude/longitude I want (the city Stuttgart), but after 1 second the maps switches to an error display and the console says: `Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError`:

[image]

After 1 second:

[image]

When I google the error, I always end up with suggestions to enable the Maps JavaScript API, for example:
[ApiNotActivatedMapError for simple html page using google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700182/apinotactivatedmaperror-for-simple-html-page-using-google-places-api)

But when I look it up in my Google Cloud Console, the Maps JavaScript API is enabled:

[image: Maps JavaScript API is enabled]

and:

[image: Maps JS API is enabled]

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you are using the correct key?

Comment: Please make sure you are using the correct API key from your Google Map project where you have enable Maps JavaScript API. If you still have errors with this, you can always file a support case to [Google Maps technical support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by creating a completely new project in the google maps console and repeating the steps of enabling the Maps JavaScript API and then generating the API Key. Then it worked.

Comment: I talked to a Google Rep and I also had to activate the Places API which was required for me since I was using an autocomplete address widget.