# I wanna integrate google map api to my react project but I get an error

Tags: reactjs

- I installed react-google-map package
- I added this component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
 
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;
 
class SimpleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key:"AIzaSyAEKXIE54WnL96aA4qln5bEzU3uOGKqhyo" }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text="My Marker"
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default SimpleMap;
```

- I add this script to index.html

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSECsV11t3FDisUFwLb5btHY-EWcP24uio&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

the error says :

#### Oops! Something went wrong.

#### This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details

The JS console show these errors :

- index.js:1 Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError
- Failed to load js?key=AIzaSyAECsV11t3FDisUFwLb5btHY-EWcP24uio&callback=initMap:1 ressource
- Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAECsV11t3FDisUFwLb5btHY-EWcP24uio&callback=initMap' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem after taking a look on [ApiNotActivatedMapError for simple html page using google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700182/apinotactivatedmaperror-for-simple-html-page-using-google-places-api) 
but when the map is open the is an overplay with  text : for development purposes only :(